# Can I use react router Link with CardActionArea?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

Can I use react router Link with CardActionArea?

Here is my code where my css is broken because How can I use Link component

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    <Link to="/Blog">
      <CardActionArea component="div" disableRipple>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="images/marmik.jpg"
          title="Marmik Desai"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Marmik Desai
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            I am front end developer.
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Link>
```

If i use below href="" in cardactionarea it will refresh page. I don't want to refresh page.

```
    <CardActionArea href="/Blog" disableRipple>
```

FOUND SOLUTION
If I use Link as CardActionArea I need to overwrite Link css. I have found below solution.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
<CardActionArea component={Link} to="/Blog">
```

Comment: How about moving Link inside of CardActionArea?

Answer (score 15):

```js
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CardActionArea } from '@material-ui/core';


<CardActionArea component={RouterLink} to={'/Blog'}>
    // ...
</CardActionArea >
```

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Same here. Please try to be a bit more verbose in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can using like this, put you `CardActionArea` component in `Link`

```
return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <Link to="/Blog" component={CardActionArea}>
                <CardMedia
                    className={classes.media}
                    image={props.thumbnail}
                    title={props.thumbnail}
                />
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" component="h6">
                        {props.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant='caption' component={"sm"}>
                        Update at {(Date(props.date).substring(0, 16))}
                        on {props.category}
                    </Typography>
                    <Divider />
                    <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
                        {props.subtitle}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Link>
            <CardActions>
                {!props.isAdmin && <Link to={props.admin_url} component={Button} size="small" >Edit</Link>}
                <Link to={props.public_url} component={Button} size="small" >Readmore</Link>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/card-action-area/#props) `CardActionArea` takes two props classes and children, add the link as a child.

```
<CardActionArea component="div" disableRipple>
  <Link to="/Blog">
    <CardMedia
      className={classes.media}
      image="images/marmik.jpg"
      title="Marmik Desai"
    />
    <CardContent>
      <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
        Marmik Desai
  </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
        I am front end developer.
  </Typography>
    </CardContent>
  </Link>
</CardActionArea>
```

Comment: I've had to change `<Link to="/Blog">...</Link>` to `<Link href="/Blog">...</Link>` to overcome the compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

In `CardActionArea` set `component` prop to `Link` and `to` to your desired URL. This way you can use browser's back and forward button to navigate in your React application.

For example:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Card,
  CardActionArea,
  CardContent,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";

<Card>
  <CardActionArea
    component={Link}
    to="YOUR-URL"
  >
    <CardContent>
      <Typography variant="h5">
        Card Title
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
        Card Description
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>
  </CardActionArea>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to keep the same `Button` style.

```js
import { Link, LinkProps } from 'react-router-dom'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'

const CardButton: React.FC<LinkProps> = ({ children, ...linkProps }) => (
  <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} {...linkProps}>
    <Button size="small" color="primary">
      {children}
    </Button>
  </Link>
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly and doesn't interfere with the Material UI action area / button styling!